# How to understand the logic of the below code?

Tags: javascript

This is the code. Would someone help me to understand the logic behind it?

```
function myArrayMax(arr) {
    var len = arr.length;
    var max = -Infinity;
    while (len--) {
      if (arr[len] > max) {
        max = arr[len];
      }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: tutorials are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: It would be better for you to [edit] your question and explain what you _think_ the code does, and point out a specific portion that you don’t understand. This way, the answers will be more precise, and you’ll learn a lot more efficiently. Keep in mind to demonstrate your research, though.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myArrayMax(arr) {
    var len = arr.length - 1;
    var max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY; //any number will be bigger than negative infinity 
    //loop begins from the end of the array 
    while (len--) { //loop on all elements until len = 0 i.e last element
      if (arr[len] > max) { //check if current element is bigger than stored maximum number
        max = arr[len];
      }
    }
    return max;
}
```

This function returns the maximum number in an array. But A simpler, ES2015 way of accomplishing this is with the new spread operator.

```
Math.max(...arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is simply computing the largest value of the array.

```
var len = arr.length;
```

Here you get the number of elements inside the array

```
var max = -Infinity;
```

You set the initial value to -infinity to ensure that even negative values can be the biggest

```
 while (len--) {
```

While len is not 0 iterate. After it is checked, len is subtracted by 1.

```
 if (arr[len] > max) {
```

check if the value at `arr[len]` is bigger than the current max value

```
max = arr[len];
```

if it is bigger assign the larger value (`arr[len]`) to `max`

```
return max;
```

return the max value (largest value) of the array

Answer (score 1):

Tricky parts

`-Infinity` will always be less than any value so every item will be larger, for empty array the function will return that value.

`len--` is reverse array loop, it first check if the value is true where any number other than 0 will be true and then it will decrement the value. so it will match the index in array (because last element is length - 1). if the value will be 0 it will stop the loop.